# NFS mounted XFS file systems not visible using xfs_quota

Tags: centos, nfs, rhel7, xfs, quota

With CentOS7, I made the leap to XFS (from ext4) and since then I have been unable to query quotas on NFS Clients via the `quota` or `xfs_quota` commands.  The `xfs_quota` command also **does not** report any information relating to the NFS mounted XFS file systems.  The CentOS7 NFS Server **does** enforce those quotas over NFS, which is nice, but that can be even more frustrating when NFS Client users bump up against quota limitations, since there is no indication of the real problem.

The following "Workaround" allows users to query disk usage of their NFS mounted file systems, but is **not** an accurate or sufficient substitution for `quota`/`xfs_quota` queries, nor is it an intuitive solution when quota restrictions are being enforced...

```
du ‐s .[A‐z]* * | sort ‐n
```

I've danced around this issue long enough, and would really appreciate if the community were able to assist with understanding why reporting user quotas across XFS formatted NFS shares is not working.  CentOS and RHEL support forums are all turning up empty.

***Notes:***

- I have the `uquota,gquota` options in the `/etc/fstab` file on the
  NFS Server, as so...

  ```
  /dev/mapper/nfs-home  /home        xfs    defaults,uquota,gquota    0 0
  ```
- The following is the NFS mount entry in the NFS Client `/etc/fstab` file...

  ```
  123.45.67.89:/        /home        nfs    rw,hard,intr,bg           0 0
  ```
- The `rpcbind`, `quotad` and `rquotad` TCP & UDP ports are opened in the Server's firewall.
- There are subnet entries for the `rpcbind`, `quotad`, and `rquotad` services in the `/etc/hosts.allow` file.
- A query of the `mount` or `df` commands on the NFS Client(s) shows the mounted NFS shares, while the `xfs_quota -c 'df'` command does **not** return any of the NFS mounted file systems.  `xfs_quota -c 'print'` performs similarly.

  - *perhaps this is indicative of the problem???*
- The following commands return the corresponding results...

  ```
  -bash-$ xfs_quota -x -c 'quota -h -v -u <username>' /home
  xfs_quota: cannot setup path for mount /home: No such device or address

  -bash-$ xfs_quota -x -c 'quota -h -v -u <username>' 123.45.67.89:/
  xfs_quota: cannot setup path for mount 123.45.67.89:/: No such file or directory

  -bash-$ xfs_quota -x -c 'quota -h -v -u <username>' 123.45.67.89:/home
  xfs_quota: cannot setup path for mount 123.45.67.89:/home: No such file or directory
  ```

***I am happy to provide more information on the Client-Server relationship if anyone shows interest.***